# Adding id tag to article HTML

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a way to add an id-tag to the article HTML through the Joomla interface?

At the moment I add a div in the source of the article so i get:

```
<article class="item leading-0 clearfix">
    <div id="about-me">
        <p>Article text.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

However, i would prefer setting it in the interface so that i get directly:

```
<article class="item leading-0 clearfix" id="about-me">
    <p>Article text.</p>
</article>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current article id like this:

```
$article_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');
```

Create an override for `JOOMLAROOT\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php` by copying the file to `JOOMLAROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\com_content\article\default.php`. Then add the following code wherever you want to add the article id:

```
<?php echo intval($article_id); ?>
```

Example:

```
<article class="item leading-0 clearfix" id="<?php echo intval($article_id); ?>">
    <p>Article text.</p>
</article>
```

I added `intval()` in order to get the article ID only, but you can remove it if you want. If you do, `$article_id` will be something like **24joomla** because `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id')` seems to return both the id and the alias together. I'm not sure why, maybe someone else can explain it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Took a bit of tinkering but figured it out due to your answer